# Fix if condition php & and or in same if range

Tags: php, if-statement, range

Trying to add **&** and **or** in same if but the or condition is not working

```
else if ($usuario = 12 & $banca <=3 or =>7){
    echo "ok";
    }
```

only working when `$banca <=3` but not working when `$banca >=7`
What is wrong?

**the range I am trying to check is between <=3 and >=7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. A more simple one and a more complex one: syntax and operators' precedence.

First of all, the operator `=` is for assignment, not comparisons. Therefore the result of `$usuario = 12` is `12`. Following that, you have a bitwise operator `&` that will output `0` if `$banca > 3`, else `12`. And finally you are taking that result and checking if it is `>= 7`. In other words: using the operators without knowing them won't get you anywhere. Please, dig deeper into php language.

Although your syntax is valid in PHP, the operator precedence is also messing the result. Take a look at [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for PHP. That is one of the reasons that linters and best-practices manuals will instruct you to add parentheses to make your criteria clear, not depending on *obscure* operator precedences.

Now, how do we fix it? Again, please study a little further on the operators of PHP and its syntax. There are some good courses available and also the [PHP's official manual](https://www.php.net/). But, not to leave you hanging, here is what your condition should look like:

```
if ($usuario === 12 && ($banca <= 3 || $banca >= 7)) { ... }
```